# cPanel email forwarder pipe to program not working

Tags: php, email, cpanel

Ok, so I noticed on an older version of cPanel it would give you this option to "Fixup Piped Program" after assigning a forward email address to a php script.

[image: old cpanel fixup piped program]

In a newer version of cPanel this option is not present. I have tried changing the permissions of the file (0700, 0744, 0777) and making sure the proper hash bang is at the top, but no luck. I've see a few other users with the same issue. https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/fixup-piped-program.136809/

I've tried connecting by SSH and issue a chmod command but that still does not work.

I'm using the basic php script for testing purposes

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php -q
<?php
$date = date('Ymdhis');
$fd = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
$email = "";
while (!feof($fd)) {
    $email .= fread($fd, 1024);
}
fclose($fd);
$fdw = fopen($date.'.txt', "w+");
fwrite($fdw, $email);
fclose($fdw);
?>
```

So any ideas on how to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Must specify the absolute path for the file creation

```
$fdw = fopen('/home/username/'.$date.'.txt', "w+");
```